# Is "cold brew" an oxymoron?

Tags: cold-brew, terminology

Dictionaries seem to agree that brewing requires *hot* water. I have checked definitions in the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, the (British) *Oxford Dictionary of English*, and a thesaurus.

So how about the expression we most use for getting a coffee drink out of cold water: "cold brew" ?

Comment: FWIW I have also heard a beer called a "cold brew". Maybe because things brew better when hotter so we assume heat has to be a part?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the term is an oxymoron.

[Miriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brew) agrees with your definition of brewing involving hot water:

> to prepare (as tea) by infusion in hot water

That is why the word *cold* is used as a qualifier to show that it is done with cold water rather than hot water.